# Можно ли из отдельного потока запустить функцию в главном потоке в c/c++?

Tags: c++, linux, c, windows

Не совсем понимаю как это сделать. Например в android в отдельном потоке можно запустить функцию `runOnUIThread ( );`. а в gtk, `g_idle_add`. то есть если мне нужно передать из сети какие то данные на виджет в gtk, то я использую `g_idle_add`, и он добавляет в основной цикл выполнение функции. что-то не пойму. я даже пример не смог написать нормальный. вот что написал. мне надо, чтобы из отдельного потока, выполнилась функция в главном потоке.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

class Thread {
    public:
        pthread_t t1;
        Thread ( ) {
        }
        void run ( void *(*func) (void *data) ) {
            pthread_create ( &t1, NULL, func, this );
        }
        void runOnUI ( ) {
            printf ( "main thread\n" );
        }
};

static void *func ( void *data ) {
    Thread *it = ( Thread * ) data;

    it->runOnUI ( );

    return NULL;
}

int main ( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    Thread *t = new Thread ( );
    t->run ( func );
    pthread_join ( t->t1, NULL );
}
```

Comment: пока вопрос слишком общий т.к. решение сильно системно-зависимо... если кратко, то для *nix-систем обычно в основном цикле находится ожидание событий в `poll`/`select`; в таком случае между основным потоком и вторым устанавливается труба (она слушается в `poll`'е) и чтобы пробудить основной поток в неё посылается какой-нить байт, а адрес функции и аргументы сохраняются в разделяемой памяти... после пробуждения основной поток просто извлекает фунцию и вызывает её с переданными аргументами...

Comment: @Fat-Zer что-то я не понял? как можно из select извлечь функцию? указатель на адрес функции?

Comment: Приведенные примеры не запускают функцию в другом потоке, а добавляют задачу в очередь другого потока.

Comment: @xverizex, труба/`poll` используются только для пробуждения потока, «*а адрес функции и аргументы сохраняются в разделяемой памяти*»

Answer (score 2):

В main нужно ждать сигнал, и после выполнять задачу. В плюсах `std::thread` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable , в си `pthread_t`. https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables

Вот пример с Си++ классами и с POSIX нитями.

```
/*

g++ -lpthread -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic  waits.cpp -o waits

*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t  lock ;
pthread_cond_t  cond ;

class Thread {
    public:
        pthread_t t1;
        int task  ;
        Thread ( ) { task = 0 ;
        }
        void run ( void *(*func) (void *data) ) {
            pthread_create ( &t1, NULL, func, this );
        }
        void runOnUI ( ) {
            printf ( "main thread\n" );
        }
};

static void *func ( void *data ) {
    Thread *it = ( Thread * ) data;
    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    it->task = 1 ;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    
    return NULL;
}

int main ( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    pthread_cond_init(&cond,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock,NULL);

    Thread *t = new Thread ( );
    
    t->run ( func );
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    while (t->task == 0) {
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&lock);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    
    t->runOnUI ( );
    
    pthread_join ( t->t1, NULL );

    delete t ;
    
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
}
```

Нить функцией `func` посылает сигнал с переменной, что задача №1 появилась. А функция `main` проверяет сигналы и если задача №1 всё-таки есть то её выполняет.

Comment: проверка условия должна идти до `pthread_cond_wait()`. Иначе это может вызвать бесконечное ожидание...

Comment: Спасибо, забыл эту проблему. @Fat-Zer